# How to update managed object data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have started my first core data application. I am working with one entity right now called 'Folder'.

The first view controller displays all the Folders in a tableview, which I can add to and it reloads the data. This works fine because It uses the fetch request to populate the table.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var error: NSError?
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]

    self.events = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Folder]        

    self.UITable.reloadData()

 }
```

However when segueing to another view controller via the table cell I pass on the selected Folder data to the controller using the index path. e.g.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FolderDetailsViewController
        let indexPath = UITable.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let selectedFolder = folders[indexPath!.row]
        destinationVC.selectedFolder = selectedFolder        
    }
 }
```

My second view controller uses the data passed from the first table view to display in textfields:

```
var selectedFolder: Folder!
folderNameLabel.text = selectedFolder?.title
folderDetailsLabel.text = selectedFolder?.details
folderDateLabel.text = displayDate
```

I then have a modal to edit/save the folder data in a modal appearing from the second controller:

```
//Edit and save event

   let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
            //Error
            var error: NSError?

            //Storing Data from fields
            SelectedFolder!.title = FolderName.text
            SelectedFolder!.details = FolderDetails.text
            SelectedFolder!.date = FolderDate.date

            context?.save(&error)

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

When dismissing the modulate data is not updated, I have to go back to the first controller to reload the data and segue again.

I think this is because I have no `NSFetchRequest` (or NSFetchResultsController) to get the most recent changes.

What is the best method to reload the data of the `selectedFolder` when I make the changes in the modal ?

Comment: I would remove the modal editor view and just use your second view controller to edit the folder objects. This is a very common design for iOS app. The iOS Contacts app is a good example.

Comment: @PeterZhou So I could just disable the text fields to edit when loaded, and when I tap edit then enable them to edit and save ?

Comment: Yes. Your view will have two mode. Viewing mode and editing mode.

Comment: If you think thats too much of work and your modal view is presented in full screen, the easiest way to solve your problem is reload your folder object in viewWillAppear. Or you have to find a way to refresh your second view.  You can employ NSNotification, Delegation, or KVO.

Comment: Currently I am trying to reload the object as following: `func viewWillAppear() { moc!.refreshObject(selectedFolder, mergeChanges:true)}` but have no luck. Might just change the view controller for edit/view mode. Still learning about Core Data one step at a time

Comment: refreshObject will not refresh your view. refreshObject won't help you in this case since you only used core data on the main thread.

Comment: Instead of calling refreshObject(). In viewWillAppear(), do this: folderNameLabel.text = selectedFolder?.title
folderDetailsLabel.text = selectedFolder?.details
folderDateLabel.text = displayDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refresh your second view in viewWillAppera() if your modal view is presented in full screen.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { 
{ 
  folderNameLabel.text = selectedFolder?.title
  folderDetailsLabel.text = selectedFolder?.details
  folderDateLabel.text = displayDate
}
```

Comment: is you modal view presented in full screen? If yes, can you added a breakpoint in the line folderNameLabel.text = selectedFolder?.title to check viewWillAppear is called?

Comment: Yes it is, I checked if the function viewWillAppear gets called and it doesn't :/

Comment: @JKSDEV viewWillAppear should be called automatically... To force it, a quick hack is to call self.presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear() before dismissing the modal view.

Comment: I have a missing argument error, so I put (true) but still no luck. I use it right before dismissing the modal.

Comment: @JKSDEV so i am not familiar with swift. The function signature was wrong. see updated answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. I am unsure why it uses the updated details in viewDidLoad when closing the modal though

Comment: @JKSDEV viewDidLoad? Or you want to know why the selectedFolder was updated automatically in your second view controller?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would want to call `moc.refreshObject(folder, mergeChanges:true)`

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject:mergeChanges:).

Comment: Sorry it seemed I added the create new folder code instead of the 'Edit folder' code. Would I use a similar method on context ? also if this is called in the modal how would it effect the Folder details display controller ?

Comment: I would imagine that you would want to call it on the folder details controller in `viewWillAppear` so that you always know every time you visit the controller that you have the most up-to-date information.